# Symfony 2 UniqueEntity constraint validator

Tags: validation, symfony-2.1

Can somebody explain me why UniqueEntity **constraint** class defines:

```
// ...

public $service = 'doctrine.orm.validator.unique';

public function validatedBy()
{
    return $this->service;
}

//...
```

And not simply:

```
public function validatedBy()
{
    return "UniqueEntityValidator";
}
```

UniqueEntityValidator class exists and has all the logic it needs. Whats the point of service here?

I'm asking this because now I cannot use UniqueEntity outside Symfony framework due to some dependencies.

Comment: This allows you to override the validator.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As described in this [recipe for the Validator component](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/validation/custom_constraint.html#constraint-validators-with-dependencies), `validatedBy()` returns an alias, not a service directly. This allows you to configure your own `Validator` service in the DIC:

```
services:
validator.unique.your_validator_name:
    class: Fully\Qualified\Validator\Class\Name
    tags:
        - { name: validator.constraint_validator, alias: doctrine.orm.validator.unique }
```

As this `UniqueEntity` constraint is part of the bridge, it means you should use it in a Symfony2 context. That's why you can't really use it outside of the framework.

But you can change this `service` value to a class name. Attributes are public: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bridge/Doctrine/Validator/Constraints/UniqueEntity.php, and according to the documentation given above, it will work.